# Troubles with this $\int{\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was practising integrating and I have problem with this one:
$$\int{\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}dx$$
I wanted to do it with substitution. Let
$$t=\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}$$
Then $$x=1\pm\sqrt{t^2+2}\quad dx=\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+2}}$$
Then 
$$\int{\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}dx=\int{\dfrac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2+2}}dt}$$
And now I don't know, what to do next. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: I would use the adequate Euler substitution http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A752+euler+substitution . Alternatively complete the square and use a trigonometric substitution.

Comment: Thx, I will try it. We have started integrating a short time ago and as I don't remember all possible substitions, I get sometimes stuck :)

Comment: complete the squares!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard method for this type of integral is to use a hyperbolic sunstitution, namely $x-1=\sqrt{2}\cosh\theta$. I think you'll find this easier.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int{\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}dx=\int\sqrt{(x-1)^2-2}\ dx$$
Use the substitution $x-1=\sqrt 2 \sec\theta$ and proceed.